# Foreach: Replicating seed outside of foreach

Tags: r, foreach

I am trying to store a seed within each repetition of the foreach loop. If something is going wrong with one repetition, then I want to be able to easily call up the seed and assess the simulated data. An example below shows how I am storing the seed with the generated data and drawing a value from a standard normal distribution.

```
set.seed(1)
library(foreach)
library(doRNG)

cl <- makeCluster(no_cores_to_use)
registerDoParallel(cl)


out <- foreach(i=1:2) %dorng% {   

  store <- .Random.seed
  value <- rnorm(1)

  result <- list()
  result$seed <- store
  result$value <- value

  return(result)
}
stopCluster(cl)


out[[1]]$value
```

[1] 0.7457097

However, when I go to set the seed to repetition 1 (i=1), the matching rnorm value does not match what the foreach loop has produced.

```
.Random.seed <- out[[1]]$seed
rnorm(1)
```

[1] -0.3262334

I have seen some answers suggest to `set.seed(i)` within the foreach loop. Can anyone advise how to save the seed within each foreach loop, as in my code above?

Comment: `doRNG` uses a different RNG than base R (according to the documentation it uses L’Ecuyer’s combined multiple-recursive generator). If you want reproducibility, set a seed (using `set.seed`) before the loop. R's documentation specifically discourages messing with `.Random.seed`.

Comment: I would use a workflow framework like R targets to manage seeds, parallelism and cache invalidation of downstream steps if something upstream changes. In very simple contexts, `set.seed(i)` is a very concise way for seed management.

Comment: @danlooo But `set.seed(i)` results in bad random properties. `doRNG` aims to provide a way to have good randomness with reproducibility for parallel computations. Don't set a seed in each iteration.

Comment: @Roland yes: This is why it's only a good idea in simple contexts, e.g. w/o any doRNG.

Comment: Hi both, in my simulation study if a method fails in rep r, I need to be able to generate the data under rep r's seed to see what is breaking. If I set the seed before the foreach loop, that won't help me with the data-generating function for a specific rep.